# How to start video at a specific time using media source buffer and fragmented mp4 without downloading entire segments?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

I'm trying to use media source with source buffer on a fragmented mp4 file, I want to start the video at a specific time, say 10 second. I'm not able to find any example as such using sourcebuffer and media source.
I'm able to stream the video from 0th second to full, I need help in starting video playback from a desired timestamp
I tried with sourceBuffer.appendWindowStart, / sourceBuffer.timestampOffset that was not working as expected, or maybe my understanding of it is not correct.
I'm trying to follow this [example](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferWhenNeeded.html), in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/video-test-forked-kjgqq?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the `video.currentTime` on line 46 of the example you reference (before doing `video.play()`).

The system will start playing video once you have appended segments that refer to that timestamp.

Comment: Here as well I'll still have to download all the segments, lets say each segment is of 2 seconds, and I want to play video at 12s, I still have to download all the segments till 12th second, I dont want to do that.
video.currentTime will just move the video timeline to there

Comment: You don't have to do that. You just have to 1. download the initialization segment, 2. download the segment closest to your 12s. You control the parameters of your encoding, most likely are encoding from start to finish, each segment you generate contains a part of the video. You simply append the parts you need and set the `currentTime` to where you need.